# jQuery - Iteration problem

Tags: jquery, iteration

This is probaby really easy for you guys. Its a real hassle for me..

I want to add a new link next to all of my other links.

Could someone help me out? Please!?
http://jsfiddle.net/Ahndm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$("a")` in your loop, use `this` to reference the current element, like this:

```
$(this).after("<span> <a href='" + newURL + "" + ID + "'>"+ newPlace + "</a></span>");
```

[Here's the updated/working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ahndm/2/).  Any time you're inside a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) you can use `this` which is the current DOM element, using `$("a")` selects *all* anchors, creating `n^2` links.

Comment: @alfred - You asked a question, setup a demo and laid out what you wanted very clearly.  That's not stupid at all, you know how to seek help and ask questions, that's years beyond most programmers :)